# How to count rank/position of products on e-commerce website?

Tags: javascript, dom, e-commerce

I am wanting to automate the counting of product positions on an e-commerce website that is not myself (walmart, home depot, etc.)  As of right now I am at a loss how to do this and any direction on how to get going would be most appreciated. I was planning on just crawling and exporting the data (which I can do no problem) and than having excel handing the counting, but I would prefer another method so I can count only certain items, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you're capable of doing basic scraping, but if you'd like to do something more specific than grabbing all the data on the page, perhaps you could try something like [Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/welcome.html)?